# How do I implement RecordAction in Bot Framework?

Tags: node.js, bots, skype, botframework, telegram

I'm trying to build recording functionality into my bot through RecordAction (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/calling-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.recordaction.html) but can't seem to get it to work.

This is the code I'm trying and I get it gray thin box in the emulator. I'm using Node.js for the bot.

```
bot.dialog('record', function (session) {
    session.send("Please record...");
    var msg = new calling.RecordAction(session, {playBeep:true});
    session.endDialog(msg);
}).triggerAction({ matches: /^record/i });
```

And does RecordAction only work in Skype? I would like to use it on Telegram, etc. but can't see much documentation telling me where it works and where it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find an answer for the second part of your question.

From the [documentation page for IRecordAction](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/calling-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.irecordaction):

> Record action is interactive action where Skype user audio is recorded.

So I don't think it works for any channels other than Skype.

Comment: Just realized I had asked this question. You are correct, Caller is Skype only

I had to use Attachments functionality to receive recordings